# Inconsistent retrieval of "folders" in AWS S3 depending on how the bucket is populated

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I have some Java code that tries to retrieves a list of files and folders from an S3 bucket. What I'm really interested in for the purpose of this question is the folders.

```
ListObjectsRequest req = new ListObjectsRequest()
                                .withBucketName(bucket_name)
                                .withPrefix(prefix);
ObjectListing listing;
do {
    listing = client.listObjects(req);
    for (S3ObjectSummary summary : listing.getObjectSummaries()) {
        System.out.println("key: " + summary.getKey());
    }
    req.setMarker(listing.getNextMarker());
} while (listing.isTruncated());
```

For buckets which I created manually in the AWS web console UI, I get a list of both files and folders:

```
key: foo/
key: foo/hello.txt
key: bar/
key: bar/world.txt
```

When I use a bucket where I uploaded all files programmatically in Java with `TransferManager` and `Upload`, the folders don't get returned:

```
key: foo/hello.txt
key: bar/world.txt
```

Why does this discrepancy exist?

In the AWS web console, these two buckets look and act identically, as far as I can tell. Why do they behave differently when I try to retrieve the keys programmatically? Everything I've read implies that the concept of folders in S3 is just a convenience, and I don't see any way to programmatically create a folder that I can subsequently retrieve via `listObjects`.

How can I list the folders?

Answer (score 0):

There's a chicken-and-egg problem with the S3 console, and what you're seeing is evidence of the workaround.

There are indeed no folders in S3, but for convenience, the console displays folders in a hierarchy, based on the `/` delimiter appearing in paths.

But since folders only "exist" because there are objects that appear to be "in" the folder, there is no mechanism for displaying "empty" folders in the console... and before you can manually upload a file "into" a folder, you have to select that folder, which of course doesn't exist, so it can't be displayed or selected.

Unless, of course, you had an empty file with a zero-length name inside the folder.

Re-read that again, because I'm not making most of this up.

That's essentially what you are seeing.  Create a folder called `foo` in the console, and you'll have an empty object named `foo/` in your bucket.  Which, if you think about it in just the right way, is a file called "" (empty string) in a folder called `foo` with delimiter `/`.  Obviously, a file can't have "" as a name, so from "inside" the folder, the file doesn't exist, but from "outside" the folder, it's enough to cause the folder to visibly appear in the console, even if empty.

This object serves no apparent purpose other than to cause a `foo` folder to appear in the console, even if/when there are no files with the prefix `foo/` in the bucket, presumably to ease the transition for people who think of S3 as conventionally hierarchical.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using [minio-java](https://github.com/minio/minio-java) library:

```
import io.minio.MinioClient;
import io.minio.Result;
import io.minio.errors.ClientException;
import io.minio.messages.Item;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class ListObjects {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException, ClientException {
    System.out.println("ListObjects app");

    // Set s3 endpoint, region is calculated automatically
    MinioClient s3Client = new MinioClient("https://s3.amazonaws.com", "YOUR-ACCESSKEYID", "YOUR-SECRETACCESSKEY");

    String bucket = "mybucket"
    String prefix = ""
    boolean recursive = false
    // list objects
    Iterator<Result<Item>> myObjects = s3Client.listObjects(bucket, prefix, recursive);
    while (myObjects.hasNext()) {
      Result<Item> result = myObjects.next();
      Item object = result.getResult();
      System.out.println(object);
    }
  }
}
```

As prefix here is `""` and recursive is `false` it will print the top level folders in the bucket